# Visual Studio 2017 Asp.Net Core project doesn't copy dependent dll file on build

Tags: c#, dll, asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2017
Asp.Net Core project doesn't copy dependent dll file on build into bin folder. That happens only on publish.

Before .Net Core I can "Copy local" dependent dll.

How can I explain to Visual Studio that it should copy nuget package dll into bin folder?

[Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vchcm.png)

[Package options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuekN.png)

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the Properties of the DLL file?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vchcm.png

Comment: What are the `Properties` of that DLL?

Comment: I mean .net core project on bulid don't include dependent packages into ./bin folder

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuekN.png

Comment: What did you conclude from this @ValeryYegorov? Should there be a ``/bin`` folder?

Comment: Hi @RasmusBækgaard. I added  /lib folder to project and set reference to that folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open your `csproj` file on any text editor outside Visual Studio.

You can see next lines of code:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>      
</PropertyGroup>
```

Just change the PropertyGroup section as:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

More details you can review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837638/how-to-get-net-core-projects-to-copy-nuget-references-to-build-output) and [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4837).