# How to turn off language specific output for .NET Core applications?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, .net-core

I've added this line of code, [to make all Nuget assemblies copy to output folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837638/how-to-get-net-core-projects-to-copy-nuget-references-to-build-output):

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

However, now I see many folders in the output director, that I think belong to culture-specific assemblies:

[image]

What are they? How do I disable them?

Comment: This is currently hard to impossible to do because the msbuild items used to determine the build output don't have any metadata to distinguish them resource satellite assemblies from "real" assemblies. The way these assemblies are resolved are going to change soon (2.1) and I've asked for the metadata to be added in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458) with a backlink to this question which could allow filtering based on locales in the future.