# Assembly referenced in csproj is not copied to output directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration">
        <HintPath>..\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
        <Private>true</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage">
        <HintPath>..\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll</HintPath>
        <Private>true</Private>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The reason is that is because I don't want [all assemblies from all .NET Core to get copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837638/how-to-get-net-core-projects-to-copy-nuget-references-to-build-output) to my output folder.

Now setting `Copy Local` to `Yes` in Visual Studio equals to `<Private>true</Private>` in `csproj` file.

The problem is, these DLL files are not getting copied to the output directory. What's more irritating is that I've added the same exact line of codes to a similar project, and only one of the files is getting copied to the output.

What can be the problem here? How do I debug this? I've made sure that these file exist and their relative path are correct.

Comment: Can you run `dotnet --info` and share the version of the SDK you are using? Also, what `TargetFramework` are you using? netcorapp2.0?

Comment: @PeterMarcu, `dotnet --info` shows that I'm using `2.1.21. Also the `TargetFramework` is set to `netcoreapp2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

> What can be the problem here? How do I debug this? I've made sure that these file exist and their relative path are correct.

According to your description, I have created a `Console App (.NET Core)` with target framework `.net core 2.0`, add your code snippet into the `.csproj` file. All Dll files are copy to the output directory without any error.

To debug this issue, I suggest you could double check the relative path of Dll files(Though you have make sure it) and the output path:

**To double check the relative path of Dll files**:

Since you are reference the dll file to your project directly, you can check the Assemblies whether exists yellow warning symbol or not:

[image]

To make sure the relative path is correct, we could add the dll file manually: Right click the `Dependencies`->`Add reference`->`Browse`->Select the dll file and add it.

**The output path:**

The default output path of .net core project should be: `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\`. When you set `Copy Local` to `Yes`, the dll files will copy to the folder `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\`. If dll files not copy to that folder, please check the output path of your project: Properties->Build->Output path.

If above info nor help you debug this issue, please share more info to us, for example, the project type, the `.csproj` file or any other special settings for this project.