# How to configure a .NET Core project to copy a specified NuGet reference to the build output?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

A have a .NET Core project and i want to copy a specified NuGet reference (assembly.dll) to the build output because i'm using a dependency injection component that searches de bin folder for the types.

I know that i could use this, but it copies all the nugets when I only want a specific nuget package to be copied:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get .NET Core projects to copy NuGet references to build output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837638/how-to-get-net-core-projects-to-copy-nuget-references-to-build-output)

Comment: Do you control this DI component? there are new APIs ("DependencyContext") to scan the logical assembly closure of an application (based on the .deps.json file) instead of enumerating files on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Visual Studio...
Project->Properties->Build Events

"Put this in the Post-build event command line:" box

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)assembly.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Or add this to your project file:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy &quot;$(SolutionDir)assembly.dll&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: That would work, though its not the perfect solution because I have to update the postbuild cmd every time the nuget is updated to a new version.