# Referencing the NuGet package MailKit in an Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I created a small project which works fine uploaded to Azure as a WebJob.   I then added a NuGet reference to MailKit so that it would send emails.   From my computer, this works fine and sends emails.

When I uploaded the email enabled project, the following error occurred

```
[05/31/2018 14:04:05 > c30776: ERR ]   An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (myProject.deps.json) was not found:
[05/31/2018 14:04:05 > c30776: ERR ]     package: 'MailKit', version: '2.0.4'
[05/31/2018 14:04:05 > c30776: ERR ]     path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/MailKit.dll'
```

Which I'm guessing is because the MailKit NuGet package is not installed/available on the Azure server.   How do I reference MailKit in my Azure WebJob?   Am I supposed to add the package reference somewhere else in my Azure or do I need to reference a central instanct of MailKit?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the MailKit reference. So you could use the  a `<PropertyGroup>` inside your `.csproj` file to **enforce copying NuGet assemblies to the built output**:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Then you will get all the dll you needed as following:
[image]

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837638/how-to-get-net-core-projects-to-copy-nuget-references-to-build-output?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Also you could publish your netcore console to **Folder** when publish to azure and [upload the zip folder to azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/). It can include all the reference and json files you needed.

And then put the whole folder to zip folder and upload to azure as webjobs.

[image]