# Run .net core 2 console app in Pre-build event

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-2.0, prebuild

I have a .net core 2 project where I want to run another .net core 2 project in the pre-build events.

All my previous projects were developed using framework 4.x, which upon building generated .exe files. This .net core does not. How can I achieve the same result as the old code from my previous projects:

```
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\MyProjectName\bin\$(Configuration)\MyProjectName.exe
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: If the problem is only with lack of `exe` file, the solution is to use `dotnet blabla\MyProjectName.dll`

Comment: I tried that, the filepath is now  `dotnet $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\ProjectName\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp2.0\ProjectName.dll` but it's throwing me the error "-532462766"

Comment: This might be relevant to your dotnet error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43841481/507793

Comment: @Matthew I'll take a look when I'm home. How did you find a relevant search for that error code? When pasting that into google I literally get nothing.

Comment: I know nothing of that specific error code, I just know that I have issues running apps from the `/bin` directory due to not all dependencies being copied there.

Answer (score 0):

- Actually i had the same issue before then i tried another solution, run the 2nd .net
  core app during the startup of the 1st one.
- as we can run .net core app from command prompt if we navigated to the directory that contains (.csproj) and opened new command prompt window then run command

> dotnet run

- here is the code

> ```
> public static void ExecuteCommand(string command, string workingDirectory)
> {
> var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
> processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
> processStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
> processStartInfo.Arguments = "/k " + command;
> processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
> processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
> Process proc = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
> }
> ```

- then you can call it like that

> ```
> // the directory that contains (.csproj)
> var appWorkingDirectory = @"D:\\Examples\\MyApp";
> ExecuteCommand("dotnet run", appWorkingDirectory);
> ```

- notice that will open a show the command prompt window and if you want
  to hide it just set

> processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

**hope this can help you**