# why ignore wwwroot/lib when using ASP.NET core?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am trying to create a web app using ASP.NET core, d3.js and jquery. I hired someone on upwork to create the app. He was able to get it working on my local machine by adding libraries d3, jquery, and others under `wwwroot/lib`. However, on the remote github repository, these libraries are not included.  I have seen others on stackoverflow also not include the libraries when pushing to remote and was wondering why this is the case.

I would like to publish my app using Azure, but when I do this I get an error and I believe it's because the libraries are missing. I know that I can just add the libraries to the remote repository, but I don't think this is the correct method.  how are the libraries added with MS Azure?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the exact error mesagge, just in case it is not due to what you think.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to a  inside your `.csproj` file to enforce copying NuGet assemblies to the built output:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

However, note that the build output (`bin/Release/netcoreapp*/*`) is not supposed to be portable and distributable, the output of `dotnet publish` is. As you have said, you get work in local, so copy the assemblies to the build output is probably very useful when the app is upload to azure.

For more details, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837638/how-to-get-net-core-projects-to-copy-nuget-references-to-build-output?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).