# Enabling transitive project references in .Net Framework => .Net Standard project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project-reference, msbuild-projectreference

I've got a project setup as follows:

```
Project B has a dependency on Project A

Project C has a dependency on Project B
```

I would like Project C to have access to Project A's types transitively. However, in my Project C (.Net Framework 4.8) referencing Project B (.Net Standard 2.0) it can't resolve any types from Project A (.Net Standard 2.0).

My understanding is the new way of doing things transitive project references are enabled by default, yet I can't build Project C without adding a direct reference to Project A as well.

I've tried playing with `<IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets>` and `<PrivateAssets>none</PrivateAssets>` as well as `<DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>false</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>` with no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697901/why-is-this-nuget-dependency-missing-when-compiling-net-framework-project-depen may, or may not, be helpful.

Comment: what about not exposing the types from A to project C...exposing the types might cause problems down the line if you ever want to refactor

Comment: How are you building them? `msbuild` at the CLI? Visual Studio (if so, which projects are in your solution?). `dotnet` CLI commands (which I don’t know how to use)? I expect this to work just fine…