# How to include nuget packages referenced by a class library

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a Visual Studio web app with 2 projects in the solution: the main C# app and another C# class library I wrote. The class library references some nuget packages.

When I build & run my solution I get a reference problem because the main app doesn't have the nuget packages. The only way I can get it to run is to add the nuget packages again to the main app, even though it doesn't actually use them.

Is there a way to get VS to automatically include the relevant packages in the final build?

[image]

Comment: Your main app is a net core and your class library project is also a net core?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: Please let us know if it works or not and we are willing tp help you further. And if you have a workaround, please let us know. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I have this issue also with a .Net Framework application.

Answer (score 0):

If your class library project is `net standard` and main project is non-sdk net framework project, you should add this under the csproj file of the main app:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
    
</PropertyGroup>
```

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677931/should-nugets-installed-for-library-project-also-be-installed-to-the-application/62690214#62690214) might be the same as yours.