# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' in .Net standard Class library

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

In my case I have one project which has one console project(.Net Framework 4.7.2) and one Class library project (.Net standard 2.0).
I am calling class library method which using "Newtonsoft.Json" from console app, and I receive a runtime error below:

> **System.IO.FileNotFoundException:**" 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'"

[image: Error message]

Console project code:

```
using TestSdk;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectWeb obj = new ConnectWeb("");
            string pin = obj.test("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Class library code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestSdk
{
    public class ConnectWeb
    {
        public string test(string testStr)
        {            
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(testStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve this System.IO.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774135/how-to-resolve-this-system-io-filenotfoundexception)

Comment: No @funie200 , that is diffrent than my issue.

Comment: Just a guess are u using the different versions newtonsoft library in both the projects?

Comment: Does the Newtosoft.dll get copied to your console project build destination?

Comment: If you could show the two project files, that would make it a lot easier to help you. Basically we should be able to reproduce the problem for ourselves.

Comment: (My *guess* is that you're using an "old-style" project file for the console app, and that if you change it to an SDK-style project file, that will resolve the issue due to the different handling of transitive dependencies, but that's only a guess at this point.)

Comment: add the [json package to the console application, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60876457/1466046)

Comment: But why do you have to add the json package to the console application as well?