# How to force nuget package reference dlls to be copied to output directory?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, nuget, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I added the `System.Memory` Nuget Package to my `net48` Azure Function V1 project to provide the missing dlls for a referenced `netstandard2.0` package. But as the package is not directly used in my code, the dlls are not copied to the output folder.

How can I force the dlls of the `System.Memory` package to be copied to the output folder on build? I already tried with `<IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets>` but this only copies the dlls to output folder in some cases (e. g. rebuild project). But if I run the Azure Function debugger, the dlls are getting deleted again from output folder.

Copy local does not exist for package references:
[image: Copy local does not exist for package references]

Comment: Are you just building your project, or also publishing?

Comment: The Azure Function will also get published

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:
`<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>`

Explanation:
https://www.koskila.net/how-to-copy-dependent-assemblies-to-bin-folder-on-build/