# Include assembly from another package into my NuGet package using GeneratePathProperty

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I am building a tool package which depends on another NuGet package. As it is not an usual library, it must include all dependencies into the `tools\` directory. I have the following `csproj` (only the relevant bits are shown):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <DevelopmentDependency>true</DevelopmentDependency>
    <IsTool>true</IsTool>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="16.7.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="16.7.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="4.7.2" PrivateAssets="all" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="build\*" Pack="true" PackagePath="build\" />
    <None Include="$(PkgSystem_Text_Json)\lib\netstandard2.0\*.dll" Visible="false" Pack="true" PackagePath="tools\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

So I used `GeneratePathProperty` on my dependency and try to include the assembly using generated path `$(PkgSystem_Text_Json)`. I can confirm that the path is correct by setting `Visible="true"` and inspecting my project. But the assembly is missing from my NuGet package. Seems that the generated path property does not exist at the moment of packaging. If I use an absolute path the assembly gets included but this solution is not portable.

How do I make generated path property work at packaging stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work locally by using

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="_PackLocalLockFileAssemblies" AfterTargets="ResolveLockFileCopyLocalFiles">
  <ItemGroup>
    <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

`CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` is [a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43841481/155005) to get the `PackageReference` DLLs into the bin folder. The files to-be-copied get resolved into `ReferenceCopyLocalPaths` items in the `ResolvelockFileCopyLocalFiles` target. The new target takes those resolved reference paths and adds them as `BuildOutputInPackage` items, that the `GenerateNuSpec` target takes as the input.

This also takes care of all the transitive dependencies.

[image]